# Papers/Resources on the source/process of shame and empathy

Tags: emotion, reference-request

I am an economist, and almost all work on shame (very little work has been done on empathy in economics, we typically just jump to some form of altruism) has simply been on observed outcomes. That being said, I was wondering if there are any good reference text or papers (big researcher names are welcome) on more of the nature of such emotions.

Comment: thank you for the question. what do you mean with shame being on observed outcomes? are you referring to outcomes as the "economic journals and research papers"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Empathy is a topic that has been addressed extensively by [**Frans de Waal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frans_de_Waal); he has been studying primates intensively and draws parallels between them and us. Especially the differences and commonalities between humans, bonobos and chimps is interesting. Check him out.

Scientific American (a non-peer reviewed scientific journal I'm reading a lot), had a [special issue recently](https://www.scientificamerican.com/magazine/sa/2018/09-01/) ([*Sci Am*, September 2018](https://www.scientificamerican.com/magazine/sa/2018/09-01/)) on why humans set themselves apart from other animal species. [Tomasello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Tomasello) has an interesting contribution there on the evolution of empathy and its role in the domination of mankind. An interesting read for sure.

Comment: Okay, sounds great! Thank you so much!